# How do I use form_set_error() the right way?

Tags: 7, forms

In my Drupal 7 module, I have a form and its validation handlers. I call my form from a field.tpl.php with `print render(drupal_get_form('my_form'))`; it works as expected.

The problem is in case of wrong input value.

It requires two incorrect submissions before displaying the error message: The first time, there is red border around my wrong input, and the second time, the error message is displayed (with the red border).

So, what's the right way to use `form_set_error()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form builders are not supposed to be called inside a template file, as they are being called too late. When you are calling `render(drupal_get_form('my_form'))`, the code that renders the error messages has been executed, and the eventual error messages reported from the validation handler are saved in the current session from [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7), which is called from `form_set_error()`.

The code to print the error message is in the [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--tests--themes--block_test_theme--page.tpl.php/7) file.

```
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print $messages; ?>
```

The code in `drupal_set_message()` that saves the messages to show is the following one:

```
  if ($message) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['messages'][$type])) {
      $_SESSION['messages'][$type] = array();
    }

    if ($repeat || !in_array($message, $_SESSION['messages'][$type])) {
      $_SESSION['messages'][$type][] = $message;
    }

    // Mark this page as being uncacheable.
    drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);
  }
```

Comment: Ok. I understand that using `form_set_error()` in a template file is the wrong way. So, what is the right way?

Comment: `drupal_get_form()` should not be called inside a template file, but inside a module.

Comment: Ok, I have put it in a module and have use Display Suite to display it in my page. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You should be looking at [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) instead

if you have an element like this:

```
function my_custom_module_form() {
  $form = array();
  $form['my_element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'My Text field',
    '#default_value' => 'Some default text.',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

in your validation callback function do this if you find that the values in `$form_state['values']` aren't valid

```
function my_custom_module_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do some checking on $form_state['values'], if you don't like it.
  form_set_error('my_element', 'This is the error message that will be displayed.');
}
```

Comment: In fact, that's the function I use. (I correct the error from my first post).