# Drupal login error block dispaly error

Tags: 7

I have created the module and it show the error in login block. But only problem with this did not show the error in first time. If user again enter the wrong username and password then it show the error. Why do not understand. I check the session value it store in first time but did not show on the screen only after second time.

```
function usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $form['warning'] = array(
  '#value' => t(''),
   '#weight' => 11
   );

   $form['#validate'][] = 'usermoved_form_validate_code';
 }

function usermoved_form_validate_code(&$form, &$form_state) {
   if (empty($form_state['uid'])) {
       form_set_error('warning', t('Sorry, unrecognized username or password.'));
     $_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter'] = t('The error message');
    }
  else {
    unset($_SESSION['usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter']);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at how [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) works? Look at [this topic](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18690/how-do-i-use-form-set-error-the-right-way). Or is there any reason why you can't use it? In that case, please tell us about it.

Comment: If you set specify the form field in `form_set_error()`, it should print an error message above the field. You can probably use `hook_form_alter()` to move the error message around.

Comment: The first parameter of `form_set_error()` takes your field's name. If you don't know what the name is, you can get it by `print_r($form_state['values']);` and look at the array keys. It's actually explained quite well on http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7.

Comment: Please update your question with your new code. `warning` doesn't look like an actual field. I'm not sure if you can use `form_set_error()` on a form item of the type `markup`. What's the name of the username and the password field?

Comment: i updated code the name of field is name and pass of login form

Comment: This code is working perfect for me.