# Form validation not triggered at first submit, but on second submit

Tags: commerce, forms

I'm in the need for a extra validation on an existing drupal commerce form (commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_##), strangely the validation function is not called on the first form submit, but on the 2nd submit and all the submits after the 2nd. There are multiple commerce_cart_add_to_cart_forms on a single page.

Here's my module code:

```
function val_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') !== false) {
        $form['#validate'][] = 'val_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate';
    }
}

function val_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    dpm('validating function called');
    form_set_error('quantity', t("ERROR"));
}
```

Any Ideas? 
And, as a second question: there are different $from_ids (commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_##) that will all need the same validation. Is there a way to call them all other than I did?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to a quick dummy function, tested it, and the it seems to be working fine. I created a dummy item, added it to my cart, and the that produced a print out like:

[image]

I also added a [watchdog()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) call to the validate function and that confirmed the validation was being called when it should be. I'm not sure if maybe you have something else interfering with your form alter or possibly your dpm is printing out late (I know it can happen with themes, not sure with modules), but you might want to try using watch dog to see if the validation form isn't being called when it should.

Comment: Can the reason be that there are more than one add to cart form on the page?

Comment: I doubt it, but does the validation form get called the first time if you try hitting it from a page with just one add to cart form on it (like on a node?)

Comment: sorry, could have done that before.. just tested and still the same problem. I think at least the form_set_error must be shown even if the dpm is printed late? whats happening is: first submit doesn't add the product to cart, no error. second submit: error +dpm shown, no product added. maybe a problem with form_set_error?

Comment: some more info: i'm rendering the add_to_cart forms on a node.tpl.php and using a custom module to validate those forms. Here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18690/how-do-i-use-form-set-error-the-right-way i read that this can cause problems.

Comment: Are you calling drupal_get_form() from your template?

Comment: Yes. I'm passing some parameters from a field collection to the form in my template, thats also why there are as many forms as are field collection items. Do you think thats the problem?

Comment: Yeah, it very well may be. I do know that the page rendering happens way down in the pipeline, and that could be causing your issues. You might want to take a look at using a hook like hook_preprocess in your template to render out your forms, then send those along in the $variables var.